# How should I read this dividing notation in the sigma index, aka "$|$"?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, clustering

I am reading [this paper on the Hierarchical Clustering](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/11/5/2373).

The author introduces cluster intra-compactness indicator and it is formulated as follows

$$RR_{intra}(S) = \sum_{i \in D \\ C_{k} \in S | i \in C_{k}}p_{i}' * RR_{i, C_{k}\setminus i},$$
where $D$ is the set of diagnoses, $i$ is the index of some diagnosis, $p_i$ is the empirical probability of a diagnosis occurrence. $S = \{C_1, \ldots,C_N\}$ is the clustering solution of a set of $N$ clusters denoted $C_k$, $k \in\{1, \ldots, N\}$, $RR$ is the relative risk.

I understand everything within the formula, but I cannot understand how the summation index reads in this case with the “dividing” term.

Comment: Vertical bar is often used for "such that" where other notation is more usually a colon.

Comment: Thank you! I might have overcomplicated it myself then.